# Tensor product of spin states

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, tensor-calculus, spinors

I just wanted to check that I carried out this problem correctly. I got the correct answer, but I'm not sure if what I *did* to get it is completely correct. This is from the second part of problem 3.4 in the second edition of Modern Quantum Mechanics from Sakurai. We have a Hamiltonian given by
\begin{equation}
  H=A\mathbf{S}^{(e^-)}\cdot\mathbf{S}^{(e^+)}
\end{equation}
acting on an electron-positron system in the state $\chi_{+}^{(e^-)}\chi_{-}^{(e^+)}$, which I took to be the tensor product of the individual spin states:
\begin{equation}
  \chi_{+}^{(e^-)}\chi_{-}^{(e^+)}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}_{e^-}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}_{e^+}.
\end{equation}
The two spin operators are
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{S}^{(e^-)}=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left(\sigma_x^{(e^-)}+\sigma_z^{(e^-)}+\sigma_z^{(e^-)}\right),\quad \mathbf{S}^{(e^+)}=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left(\sigma_x^{(e^+)}+\sigma_z^{(e^+)}+\sigma_z^{(e^+)}\right),
\end{equation}
so in taking their dot product, I assumed that the Hamiltonian in terms of $\sigma_i^{(e^-)}$ and $\sigma_i^{(e^=)}$ would be
\begin{equation}
  H=\frac{A\hbar^2}{4}\left(\sigma_x^{(e^-)}\otimes\sigma_x^{(e^+)}+\sigma_y^{(e^-)}\otimes\sigma_y^{(e^+)}+\sigma_z^{(e^-)}\otimes\sigma_z^{(e^+)}\right).
\end{equation}
Is this the proper way of taking the dot product of the two spin operators? I wasn't quite sure how to handle the dot product since the two operators should live in two different Hilbert spaces (or they simply *act* on their respective spaces and don't actually live in them?). When I have the Hamiltonian act on the state $\chi_+^{(e^-)}\chi_-^{(e^+)}$, I end up with
\begin{align}
  H\chi_+^{(e^-)}\chi_-^{(e^+)} &= \frac{A\hbar^2}{4}\left[\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}_{e^-}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}_{e^+}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\i\end{pmatrix}_{e^-}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}-i\\0\end{pmatrix}_{e^+}+\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}_{e^-}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\end{pmatrix}_{e^+}\right]\\
   &= \frac{A\hbar^2}{4}\left[2\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}_{e^-}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}_{e^+}-\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}_{e^-}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}_{e^+}\right]\\
   &= \frac{A\hbar^2}{4}(2\chi_-^{(e^-)}\chi_+^{(e^+)}-\chi_+^{(e^-)}\chi_-^{(e^+)}).
\end{align}
And when I take the expectation of the Hamiltonian, I get
\begin{align}
  \langle H\rangle &= \chi_+^{(e^-)}\chi_-^{(e^+)}\cdot H\chi_+^{(e^-)}\chi_-^{(e^+)}\\
&= \frac{A\hbar^2}{4}(2\chi_+^{(e^-)}\chi_-^{(e^+)}\cdot\chi_-^{(e^-)}\chi_+^{(e^+)}-\chi_+^{(e^-)}\chi_-^{(e^+)}\cdot\chi_+^{(e^-)}\chi_-^{(e^+)})\\
   &= -\frac{A\hbar^2}{4},
\end{align}
which is the correct answer. But again, I'm not sure about some of the operations that I carried out in writing $\chi_+^{(e^-)}\chi_-^{(e^+)}$ and the spin operators explicitly as tensor products, and I hope I didn't get the right answer entirely by accident.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [check-my-work questions are off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583).